# SFSafariViewController prevent smart quotes in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-safari

We use `SFSafariViewController` in our app for `OAuth`, so users type in their usernames and passwords here. This used to work fine, but ever since `iOS 11` users with an apostrophe in their usernames have issues because they didn't realize that their iPhone is now using "smart apostrophe", which is not the same as a straight apostrophe like they have in their username.

This is causing login issues.

**Is there any way to turn off iOS 11 smart quotes for HTML input fields, or to tell `SFSafariViewController` not to use them?**